# Extract "front-end" data that appears on the Report view of Power BI Desktop

Tags: json, csv, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to extract "front-end" data that appears on the Report view of Power BI Desktop. I am going to use the below example to demonstrate my question.

Here is the "Net Sales" Page of Microsoft's Sales & Returns sample report.

(References: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/sample-datasets#sales--returns-sample-pbix-file)

[image]

If we focus on the Category Breakdown section, my question is:

**Is it possible to extract data that appears in the bar chart in JSON or CSV format?**

An ideal extract would be something like:

```
{"title": "Category Breakdown", "data": {"Power BI": "$52K", "Word": "$36K", "OneNote": "$31K", ...}
```

---

**Updates:**

I know we can achieve this by clicking `More options > Export data` to save the data as a CSV file. However, I wonder if we can find a more automated way to extract all data on a Page without clicks, or do not even have to open the report (`.pbix`) file.

Comment: Not really. The closest to achieve this is to run a DAX query on the dataset via the REST API (also available in Power Automate PBI connector), this returns JSON of the first 1000 rows. You will need to have `Build` permission on the dataset.

Comment: @SamNseir Hi Sam, thanks for the comment. We prefer here a more front-end solution on the Report layer, without the Data and Model layers being involved.